# Include OCaml module in both interpreted and compiled modes

Tags: module, ocaml

Say I have some OCaml code where I need to use the `Str` module. If I run the code with the interpreter, then I have to put `#load Str.cma` to be able to use the `Str` module. But if I want to native-compile the code, then the `load` directive causes an error. How can I import the module in a way that will work in both cases?

I'm looking for either 
(a) a way to include the module that works in both modes; or 
(b) a way to load the module for the interpreter that will be ignored by the compiler, leaving me to specify it on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't put `#load` into the source file, it's not OCaml code. It's an instruction to the toplevel (as you know of course).

One possibility is to add the `#load` commands you need to your `~/.ocamlinit` file. It doesn't hurt to load a few extra modules, so you can modify your `~/.ocamlinit` only occasionally as you work on different things.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to do `ocaml my_code.ml` and `my_code.ml` uses the `Str` module, just do `ocaml str.cma my_code.ml`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use OCaml in a scripting way (using the `ocaml` binary, called toplevel), like you are describing. Scripts have the advantage that the code is readily accessible and changeable. But some problems arise:

- your script is bytecode compiled at each call, which is quite fast but far from optimal
- the directives for loading the packages you need are specific to the toplevel and not compatible with the compilers
- if you need one of the many packages from the ocaml package manager [opam](http://opam.ocaml.org) you must install opam globally which currently is linux admin work and not officially recommended

So there is no compatible syntax for ocaml toplevel and compiler invocation. Command line arguments for the toplevel would require another wrapper script.

My recommendation:

- use the toplevel for interactive development, exploration of features, and tests
- use the opam installer for your packages **and** the compiler, this will give you updatable tools
- compile your scripts to bytecode or native code depending on your requirements, compiled code is portable within the platform and fast

Compiling is quite simple for ocaml programs once you know how to specify the components.

As a side note: there is an opam package called ocamlscript that gives you a specific syntax for your packages and dependencies in a sort of script header, but compiles your script transparently to disk. Maybe this is what you want - but global opam install required.